# C++ selection pointer

Tags: c++, windows, menu

Generally, In c++

To select from 4 options (say)

1. start
2. help
3. about
4. end

we get input from user say 1/2/3/4 but instead of that way is there any modern way

like, click on that word to select that or any arrows to navigate in these options...

Note: I would like to know if it's possible in c++ without using graphics.h 
and  using  this is a console windows application

Comment: You are looking for a text based user interface like ncurses

Comment: There is nothing like that in the C++ standard library. Implementing something like this requires specifics of the operating system and the terminal emulator used. If you want to ask specifically what the Windows APIs offer, I would suggest adding the `windows` tag to your question. Otherwise you will have to look for a library such as ncurses (not sure whether there is a good Windows port) or some other, but library recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @AndyG Yes, something like that.
but is it possible using with already present libraries?
because ncurses are not predefined .h file it needs to be installed

Comment: @walnut thanks. I have added a windows tag.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the core language nor the C++ standard libraries contain any functionality that deals with pointing devices. This is true at least up to and including C++20.